# Magento: Transactional emails. How add an image from a custom template

Tags: image, magento, email, templates, transactional

I've created in my webpage a custom theme ('mytheme') and I'd like to add to a transactional email an image from this template (.../skin/frontend/mytheme/default/images/myimage.png)

I've tried some options but anyone works:

```
<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend"}}"></div>

<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend" _theme="mytheme"}}"></div>

<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend" _theme="mytheme" _package="default"}}"></div>
```

Comment: what output are you getting for each of the options you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case _package would be mytheme

```
<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend" _theme="default" _package="mytheme"}}"></div>
```

Also verify that the image is there otherwise magento will fallback to the default package

Comment: Thank you so much @changeling, I was confusing _package value with _theme value.